RLLib - testing my trained agent gives bad results
I'm using Ray (version 1.8.0) to train an agent. The agent controls a unit in a simulation, and the simulation can end in one of three different ways: "UnitADestroyed", "UnitBDestroyed" or "Timeout". My aim is to maximize the probability of the outcome "UnitADestroyed", so I give rewards accordingly. I also log the outcome of each simulation.
My code for training the agent looks like this:
config = {
    "env": "MyEnv-v0",
    "num_workers": 40,
    "num_cpus_per_worker": 1.0,
    "train_batch_size": 32000,
    "num_sgd_iter": 2,
    "framework": "torch",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "callbacks": EpisodeEndCallbacks,  # This basically just logs the outcome to stdout
}

trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, logger_creator=lambda config: ray.tune.logger.UnifiedLogger(config, logdir))

print("Starting training...")
for i in range(numIterations):
    result = trainer.train()


This seems to work, and in TensorBoard I can see the development of the average of my custom metrics. This is the average of "UnitADestroyed" in one of my runs:

This is the average of "UnitBDestroyed":

And this is the average of "Timeout":

So as you can see, "UnitADestroyed" increases from almost nothing in the beginning (which I think is realistic with a completely random agent) to about 25-30%. This is all very nice. I have also verified this by looking at a few log files from the simulations (each simulation creates its own log file).
But the problem begins when I try to test the agent after training. I do this:
for seed in range(100):
    env = MyEnv()
    env.MySeed = seed + 1001 # during training, MySeed is not set, and will therefore get a random value
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    total_reward = 0
    while not done:
        action = trainer.compute_action(state, explore=False)
        state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward

This runs the simulation 100 times (the simulation is initialized with seeds from 1 to 100, for reproducability - during training the seeds are random). I had expected to see the "UnitADestroyed" outcome 25-30 times, but didn't - it only occured 3 times on average (I have of course repeated this whole process a lot of times now), the "UnitBDestroyed" occured around anywhere between 0 and 40 times and the rest was "Timeout".
I have also tried saving the weights to files, and restoring them in a whole new process, with the exact same results. And I have tried using explore = True, but that gave even worse results ("Timeout" all the time).
So what have I done wrong? It looks very promising during training, so something is clearly being achieved here, but I'm not able to reproduce that success afterwards. I suspect I may be doing something wrong when I extract the trained agent, since the results after training seem so random???
